# Decorating ServiceStack DTOs in a PCL

Tags: c#, servicestack, nuget, dto

When you define your DTOs in a separate assembly, for example in a PCL (portable class library), and you want to use the suggested ServiceStack "New API" with the IReturn interface and RestAttributes on your request DTOs, there's no valid NuGet package to do that. The 2 DLLs you need to properly decorate your DTOs are ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll and ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll but there is no NuGet package that is PCL friendly that contains those 2 DLLs: you have to add references to those manually. And when you update to the latest NuGet package you have to re-add those references manually.. kinda annoying.

Just of thought that having a PCL friendly NuGet package that allows us to decorate DTOs would be helpful. Anyone has a better approach?

Comment: This is kinda special requirement. And as far as I know PCL as of now not completely "NOT windows only". Few libraries dare still windows only. Still Servicestack is opensource and you can manage nuget from already created nuget. I hope I am able to answer your question. let me know if you need more details.

Comment: My approach was to not use IReturn and apply attributes using TypeDescriptor